# Highcharts Pie doesn't display the labels (for some data series)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to display a simple PIE chart:

The Pie is correctly displayed (with the Labels) when I use the series data: `[ ['cars', 8], ['bikes',15] ]`
As instance:

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Vehicles',
            data: [ ['cars', 8], ['bikes',15] ]
          }]
```

BUT it doesn't display the Labels at all if I use as data: [ ['cars', 6], ['bikes',15] ]

(6 instead of 8 for cars).

In few words, for some data series Labels are shown, for some others are not shown at all!

I'm using the last HC version: Highcharts JS v2.2.4.

Do you have any ideas about this ?

thanks

Comment: Can you set up a js fiddle?  I was unable to reproduce this: http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/g6qwZ/

Comment: Can you post your highcharts code?

Comment: What is the status of this question? Did any of the below answers work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I had to work in other tasks and just today I restarted working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not duplicate the issue you are experiencing.  However I did create the below pie charts for you.

- [**cars 8 - bikes 15**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg2jz/4/)
- [**cars 6 - bikes 15**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg2jz/5/)

Maybe looking at the two examples will help you figure out what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try the data section part as following bellow

```
 data: [
        {name: 'cars', y: 8},
        {name: 'bikes', y: 15}
       ]
```

Thanks,
Arun Krishnan

Comment: thanks, I've tried it, but same result. Then it should be something about the data values.